# Set focus on text boxes on tabout Event JSF 1.2

Tags: jsf, jsf-1.2

I have a list of text boxes lined up one after other horizontally and my requirement is once user enter value in text box I need to do server side validation and if validation is passed I need to set focus to the next text box.

I have used JavaScript but that is not a maintainable solution .So can we set focus by doing some code in managed bean itself like phase listener etc.

I am using JSF 1.2 with MyFaces

Comment: Can you please share what you have done so far?

Comment: JSF executes on server side. JavaScript executes on client side. Focus of an `<h:inputText>` is focusing on the generated `<input type="text" />` on client side, and can be done using JavaScript only, not JSF. Instead, you can use ajax operations to validate the data in server side, get a proper answer on the callback of the ajax and focus to the *next* input (whatever it is).

Comment: @scubaFun Till now I have used onComplete from <a4j:support> in my <t:inputtext> once my action is complete ,I call a JavaScript function in onComplete to set focus on the next component by using document.getelementbyid().focus()

Comment: @luiggi can you please share a code snippet using callback

Comment: From your comment, you're already using RichFaces, so the callback is automatically handled in the `oncomplete` method. Please provide the relevant code to reproduce your issue, otherwise the question is unclear and may be voted to close.